# SSRS web service in java application

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, reporting-services

I am new to the SSRS web service .

I got the stub using the wsdl with the help of wsdl2java . and packaged it to jar file into my java project .

My interest is to get list of folder in Report server using the web services . similiarly the list of reports . and render the report for user.

I understand that I can get the list of folder from report using SSRS web service using the methods  `ReportService2005.listchildren()` ( C# code from MSN site).

And I can show report either by url access Or by web service.

I really dono is this to implement. I really seek help with any link poiting to tutorial or any other .

Iam ready to explore and learn instead of sample code . But any sample code if will faster my learning process.

Kinldy comment with suggestion and input

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. Instead of using wsdl2java, import the wsdl using *wsimport* tool which is available in JDK starting from v1.6:

   ```
   wsimport.exe http://<yourserver>/reportserver/reportService2005.asmx?wsdl -s <path to save package> -extension
   ```
2. Copy the resulting package to your java project. Amon other things, it will contain the ReportingService2005 and ReportingService2005Soap classes which is exactly what you need.
3. Test it with the following code:

   ```
   package testSSRS;

   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ArrayOfCatalogItem;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.CatalogItem;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ReportingService2005;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ReportingService2005Soap;

   public class mainClass {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           ReportingService2005 srv = new ReportingService2005();
           ReportingService2005Soap srvs = srv.getReportingService2005Soap();

           ArrayOfCatalogItem arr = srvs.listChildren("/", true);

           for (CatalogItem ci : arr.getCatalogItem())
           {
               System.out.println(ci.getPath() + "/" + ci.getName());
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

Best regards,
Alexey

Comment: thank you so much for responce with detail code. 
I got my jar file created out of the generated classes. using wsdls.

Comment: Hi, does your jar contain the ReportingService2005 & ReportingService2005Soap classes? When I was trying to generate stub with wsdl2java it didn't generate neither of those two, but they are essential to connect to the web service. Wsimport.exe generates them perfectly. You can find wsimport in your JDKxxx\bin folder.